# Send data through socket in C to Java server

Tags: c, sockets, encode, asn.1

I want to encode data in C client and send them to a Java server.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE  100


INTEGER_t clientNumber;
printf("Enter a number :\n  "); 
scanf("int *",&clientNumber);
Message01_t *message1;
message1 = calloc(1, sizeof(Message01_t));
message1->number = clientNumber;
char    buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
size_t  bufferLen = sizeof(buffer); 
der_encode_to_buffer(&asn_DEF_Message01, message1, buffer, bufferLen);
xer_fprint(stdout, &asn_DEF_Message01, message1); 
send( to_server_socket, &message1, sizeof( message1 ), 0 )
```

As output xer_fprint show me

```
<Message01>
    <number>1D:00:00:00:10:00:00:00:00:80:04:00:00:1A:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00...... A VERYYYY LONGGG SEQUENCE OF BYTES....
```

and in the server

> During decoding, the encoded tag value in the byte array does not match with this object's tag number!

Comment: There's a lot of code we can't see, including in particular the structure of `Message01_t`.  To send the data successfully to the Java server, you need to know what the Java server expects.  How does it know which type the messages are?  What are the rules about encoded tag values and tag numbers?  What protocol is the Java server expecting?  I think you'll need to clarify your question in a number of areas before you get any useful answers.  It might also help to identify the ASN library you're using.

Comment: Your scanf format string is wrong... check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598392/send-asn1-data-from-client-to-server-with-socket for the rest.